# How to display blog pages in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a page called Blogs, and under that I want to have pages such as Food and Life (these are actually categories of blog posts). How do I first display all blogs on my Blogs page, then for each child page display only posts of that category? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use an archive index for this (eg https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index).  You do not need to create a new template actually, since the template hierarchy will take care of it regardless (eg https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display) but certainly you could customize the appearance of these categories with category.php, archive.php, or something along those lines (best answer depends on what templates your theme already has)

If you decide to create a new page template, make sure your understand which page template is currently active on your category posts. Whatever file does that, make sure you jump up one step in the hierarchy.

For instance, if you have a file called archive.php (it's shared with author archives, tag archives, etc) and you want a custom page template to handle categories and only categories, make sure you jump up one level in the hierarchy....and create a file called categories.php, not archive.php

Also, if you create a page template, make sure you do that in a child theme!

Last, in terms of seeing your category pages, with posts only displaying for a particular category, go to posts-->categories.  Pick one of your categories that has posts in it. View it.

You can add these category archives to your menu either with the URL itself and a custom link (generally not preferable) or by adding the category itself to the menu. If you edit a menu, you should notice the option to add pages, posts, custom links, and categories on the left hand side of the edit menu screen. You may see many other options as well, depending on the theme. But the ones you want to add are under categories.

If you can't find any of this, depending on your url rewrites, try entering www.myblog.com/category/foodandlife (or whatever the food and life slug is). Often people remove /category/ so if the above doesn't work, try /foodandlife (where, again, foodandlife would be replaced by whatever slug applies to your Food and Life category)

Hope this helps!